# The code is not running after clicking on submit it show 404. I wright similer code on my desktop in my desktop it is running. can any one help me out

Tags: java, servlet-3.0, servlet-mapping

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/details">
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br> 
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
        <br> <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@WebServlet("/details")  
public class ShowDetails extends HttpServlet {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7384650098624517113L;

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String fName = request.getParameter("fname");
        String lName = request.getParameter("lname");
        
        System.out.println(fName + " " + lName );
        
    }

}
```

after clicking submit
[image]

it must print the value on console
[image]

HTML page
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<form action="/details">` to `<form action="/DemoServlet/details">`.

Since the servlet path is relative to `/DemoServlet` (you can set this in `web.xml`), the `ShowDetails` servlet will be at `localhost:2222/DemoServlet/details` and not just `localhost:2222/details`.

Comment: I just remove / from "<form action="/details"> " and its working. Thank you :)